# Unable to successfully pass parameters to Linked ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I'm trying to test basic linked ARM templates and struggling to parse a parameter to my linked template and keep getting the below error;

New-AzDeployment: 20:29:04 - Error: Code=InvalidDeployment; Message=The 'location' property must be specified for the deployment 'ResourceGroups'. Please see https://aka.ms/deploy-to-subscription for usage details.

From what I have read on the MS docs around linked templates, I believe the below should parse the 'location' parameter.

My files/code is as per the below

- azuredeploy.json - main/parent template file
- azuredeploy.parameters.json - main param file
- resourceGroups.json - linked template (contains arm to deploy 2 resource groups)

my azuredeploy.json file

```
{
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
    "_artifactlocation": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "https://someblob.blob.core.windows.net/armtemplates/"
    },
    "_artifactsastoken": {
        "type": "securestring",
        "defaultValue": "somekey"
    },
    "location": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "ukwest"
    },
    "tag_Owner": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "abc"
    },
    "network_RGName": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "RG-UKW-TEST-NETWORK"
    },
    "activtyDirectory_RGName": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "RG-UKW-TEST-ACTIVEDIRECTORY"
    }
},
"functions": [
],
"variables": {
},
"resources": [
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
        "apiVersion": "2019-10-01",
        "name": "ResourceGroups",            
        "properties": {
            "mode": "Incremental",
            "templateLink": {
                "uri": "https://someblob.blob.core.windows.net/armtemplates/resourceGroups.json",
                "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
            },
            "parameters": {
            "parameters": {
                "location": {
                    "value": "[parameters('location')]"
                },
                "network_RGName": {
                    "value": "[parameters('network_RGName')]"
                },
                "activtyDirectory_RGName": {
                    "value": "[parameters('activtyDirectory_RGName')]"
                }
            }
        }
    }
],
"outputs": {
}
```

}

azuredeploy.parameters.json

```
{
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
    "location":{
        "value": "ukwest"
    },
    "network_RGName":{
        "value": "RG-UKW-TEST-NETWORK"
    },
    "activtyDirectory_RGName": {
        "value": "RG-UKW-TEST-ACTIVEDIRECTORY"
    },
    "tag_Owner":{
        "value": "abc"
    }
}
```

}

my resourceGroups.json file

```
{
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
    "location": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "network_RGName": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "activtyDirectory_RGName": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "tag_Owner": {
        "type": "string" 
    }
},
"functions": [],
"variables": {},
"resources": [
    {
        "name": "[parameters('network_RGName')]",
        "type": "Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups",
        "apiVersion": "2019-10-01",
        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
        "dependsOn": [
        ],
        "tags": {
            "Owner": "[parameters('tag_Owner')]"
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "[parameters('activtyDirectory_RGName')]",
        "type": "Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups",
        "apiVersion": "2019-10-01",
        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
        "dependsOn": [
        ],
        "tags": {
            "Owner": "[parameters('tag_Owner')]"
        }
    }
],
"outputs": {}
```

}

Comment: *arm* tag is for ARM microcontroller, not for Azure RM. I've removed it.

Comment: Have you referred to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/linked-templates?tabs=azure-powershell#linked-template?

Comment: @JimXu I have tried to base my example on that very page, but I've still not be able to parse parameters into the linked template

Comment: @JimXu If I try to deploy just the linked template with the same parameter file the deployment works fine